# How do I hide the Library Name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

For a library how do I hide the library name within the page..For this particular library I have added some webparts and I really do not want to display the library name..I tried the below and it did not work.  At minimum I wish to make the font smaller, but just for this page

.s4-titlelogo { hidden  }  Title Text (Includes Breadcrumb)      .s4-titletext { hidden  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use F12 (developer tools) and choose the div which displays the library name.

Hide it by adding `display:none`to the div. If you want this only for the particular page, edit the page and add a content editor / script editor webpart on the page and write the styles under `<style type="text/css"></style>`